# How do I repeat a query across a set of user IDs with BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table containing user IDs and visit dates.  I need to go through the table and return a list that shows the number of unique IDs that visited that month, that month and the month before, and the previous three months.  Here's what it should look like:

```
Month  this_month  2_months  3_month
4/22    1500        726       27
5/22    2718        850       191
6/22    3112        837       183
```

Currently, I'm able to go through the database for a single ID and return each month that fulfills *one* of the conditions (1,2, or 3 month streaks).  I have no idea how to do this for every single unique ID, although I know how to gather the unique IDs in the database - here's my code:

```
# fragment
WITH users AS(SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber FROM *table*)

# 3-month streak check
SELECT DATE(Year, Month, 1) month_visited, AccountNumber, COUNT(AccountNumber) visits, 
FROM *table*

WHERE ProgramID='ProgramID' AND AccountNumber = ID 
AND DATE_SUB(DATE(Year, Month, 1), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) IN(SELECT DATE(Year, Month, 1) FROM *table* WHERE AccountNumber = ID) 
AND DATE_SUB(DATE(Year, Month, 1), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) IN(SELECT DATE(Year, Month, 1) FROM *table* WHERE AccountNumber = ID)

GROUP BY month_visited, AccountNumber
ORDER BY month_visited ASC
```

If possible, I would like to just iterate through this for each unique ID in `users`, then collapse it down by putting this inside a query like `SELECT month_visited, count(AccountNumber) FROM table, GROUP BY month_visited`, but as a complete novice I'm open to alternatives.

My apologies for the disgusting code.  I've had about 24 hours to learn BigQuery and tidy/efficient code has not been a priority given the small size of my dataset.

Comment: What does `*table*` look like? How are you defining a unique ID visiting? It seems like the numbers should go up, not down, for 1 month, 2 months, and 3 months. Is it checking that a user visited at least once every month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure this is what you for looking for, but if it is not, I believe you know enough to edit it to fit your situation. If not, please comment with more information and I will try to fix it. Also, I tried not to edit too much of your code since I do not know what the table looks like.
Hope this helps.

```
Select month_visited,

AccountNumber,

visits As current_month_visits,

LAG(visits) Over (Partition by AccountNumber Order by month_visited) AS 
prev_month_visits,

LAG(visits, 2) Over (Partition by AccountNumber Order by month_visited) AS 
two_month_ago_visits

From

    (SELECT DATE(Year, Month, 1) month_visited, AccountNumber, 
    COUNT(AccountNumber) 
    visits, 

    FROM *table*

    GROUP BY 1, 2)

Order by 2, 1
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it does something close enough for me to tweak it there!  Thank you!